# Why getView() of BaseAdapter showing image multiple times?

Tags: android, list, listview, baseadapter

I'm using the following code to make a custom `listview`. I have to show image dynamically, so all the images are added to this in Linearlayout. The problem is that these dynamic images add multiple times. Below is the code of my `getView()`.

```
    LinearLayout fbpiclayout = null;

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_event_list, null);

         fbpiclayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.fbpic_layout);

        ArrayList<String> list=  mDbManager
                .getAllValuesComingSoonFriendList(facebookEventList
                        .get(position).getEventId());


        int height = 0;


        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(i<3)
            {
                String friendPics = "http://graph.facebook.com/"
                        + list.get(i)
                        + "/picture?type=large";

                Log.d("Friends","list no "+i+" "+mDbManager
                        .getFacebookFriendName(list.get(i)));

                ImageView fbFriendimage = new ImageView(getActivity());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                vp.setMargins(3, 0, 3, 3);
                fbFriendimage.setLayoutParams(vp);
                fbFriendimage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                fbFriendimage.getLayoutParams().height = height;

                fbFriendimage.getLayoutParams().width = width_iv;
                fbFriendimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //  image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(friendPics, fbFriendimage);
                fbpiclayout.addView(fbFriendimage, vp);     

            }
        }
```

Kindly suggest me on that issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by multiple times? And why are you using a loop in the getView method?

Comment: remove if(convertView == null)

Comment: In every list item, i hav to add multiple images. these image url is stored in List. like in list postion i have 3 images. M adding these 3 images in loop to linearlayout. Multiple time means , in my list there is only 3 images but linearlayout showing 6 or 9 images in that list postion. With every time getView calling its no increase.

Comment: @Manikandan Its works but its making listview jerky and slow. Any suggetion on this?

Comment: @ Gaurav use lazyLoading, your listview will work fine.

Comment: @Manikandan m already using Lazyloading .

Comment: @ Gaurav then the listview will be like that. we cant do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
LinearLayout fbpiclayout = null;

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_event_list, null);

         fbpiclayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.fbpic_layout);

          //if the convertView was not null it would have the child view you added the 
          //  last time liner layout was used. So remove the added child view.  
          fbpiclayout.removeAllViews();

        ArrayList<String> list=  mDbManager
                .getAllValuesComingSoonFriendList(facebookEventList
                        .get(position).getEventId());


        int height = 0;


        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(i<3)
            {
                String friendPics = "http://graph.facebook.com/"
                        + list.get(i)
                        + "/picture?type=large";

                Log.d("Friends","list no "+i+" "+mDbManager
                        .getFacebookFriendName(list.get(i)));

                ImageView fbFriendimage = new ImageView(getActivity());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                vp.setMargins(3, 0, 3, 3);
                fbFriendimage.setLayoutParams(vp);
                fbFriendimage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                fbFriendimage.getLayoutParams().height = height;

                fbFriendimage.getLayoutParams().width = width_iv;
                fbFriendimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //  image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(friendPics, fbFriendimage);
                fbpiclayout.addView(fbFriendimage, vp);     

            }
        }
```

EDIT1: Try to use smart image view http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/ to improve performance....

Comment: Thanks @praful Bhatnagar  : kindly suggest me .Can we make any approach to make list smooth. M already using Lazy Adapter . I think getView is calling everytime and making listview jerky n slow.

Answer (score 0):

don't use that loop. Put that list's size in getCount(). It will work properly